# Таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Надо, чтобы после завершения таймера выдавало не `alert('Hello');`, а то, что находится в блоке `div id="block"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function timer(){
         var obj=document.getElementById('timer_inp');
         obj.innerHTML--;

         if(obj.innerHTML==0){alert('Hello');setTimeout(function(){},1000);}
         else{setTimeout(timer,1000);}
        }
        setTimeout(timer,1000);
        </script>

<div id="blocks">
Текст который покажется после завершения таймера
<div id="timer_inp">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [http://tsya.ru]()

Comment: @cnofss, Если блок будет спрятан, то ваш таймер тоже не будет виден. Оберните свой тест в какой-нибудь элемент. Тогда можно спокойно скрывать его и открывать, независимо от его "соседей"

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать, поэтому и обратился на hashcode

Comment: @cnofss, например [вот так][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/of38dtmb/1/

Comment: Не знаю почему, но на сайте не работает. Подключены библиотеки <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @cnofss, используете библиотеку, а пишите на чистом JS?)) Код оберните:

    $(function(){
       // тут ваш код
    });

Или расположите в конце страницы.

Comment: @Deonis Не могли на jsfiddle код вставить и отправить. Я просто с js вообще ни как, но иногда приходиться использовать

Comment: > Не могли на jsfiddle код вставить и отправить.

@cnofss, это что - претензия? Или на форуме вам кто-то чем-то обязан?

Comment: @Deonis нет, просто я вам сказал же, что я js не знаю, я не знаю даже как начать скрипт и т.д. Просьба просто.

Comment: @cnofss, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function timer() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('timer_inp');
  obj.innerHTML--;

  if (obj.innerHTML == 0) {
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block';
    //или через jquery:
    //$("#text").show();

    //еcли нужно скрыть цифру таймера после окончания отсчета:
    //document.getElementById('timer_inp').style.display = 'none';
    //или через jquery:
    //$("#timer_inp").hide();

    setTimeout(function() {}, 1000); //данная строка для данного примера не играет никакой роли
  } else {
    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
  }
}
setTimeout(timer, 1000);
```

```css
#text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="blocks">
  <div id="text">
    Текст который покажется после завершения таймера
  </div>
  <div id="timer_inp">10</div>
</div>
```